# I cannot get a QTCaptureSession to Capture when in a Terminal Application

Tags: objective-c, macos, qtkit

I've got a terminal application that needs to take a webcam picture and then perform some processing on it.  I'm having trouble getting it to initialize.  There's a fairly complete demo with an app called [MyRecorder](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/QTKitApplicationTutorial/BuildingaSimpleQTKitCaptureApplication/BuildingaSimpleQTKitCaptureApplication.html) in the Apple docs that uses QTKit, which I was able to make work fine.  I was also able to modify it to grab a single frame instead of a stream.

When I move this to a terminal application, the `startRunning` of the QTCaptureSession command simply does nothing.  There are no errors, and everything reports as successful, but my webcam doesn't light up, and no frames are captured.

Any idea what's going on here?  Are there any kind of security restrictions, or other kinds of restrictions that would prevent the QTCaptureSession from working?

Comment: This is just a wall of text. Please clean up the question and make it clear what you're asking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So switching to AVFoundation solved my problem.  I'm still not certain what the issue is, but for now using AVFoundation seems like the way to go since it was designed to replace QtKit anyways.